# How to solve attirbute error with profile

Tags: django

I need to create profiles in my project. I'm certain that my code is okay but still receiving the error: AttributeError at /admin/login/
'User' object has no attribute 'UserProfile' and it drives me crazy.. I have checked the whole google and couldn/t find the solution.

## models

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
                class UserProfile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='profile_pics')

        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

        def save(self):
            super().save()
            img = Image.open(self.image.path)
            output = (300,300)
            img.thumbnail(output)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

## signals

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
                def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
                    if created:
                        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)


                @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
                def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
                    instance.UserProfile.save()
```

## apps

```
class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
                    name = 'users'

                    def ready(self):
                        import users.signals
```

## html

```
       <div class="container">
            <div class="mt-5">
                    <div class="media">
                        <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{user.userprofile.image.url}}" style="max-height: 100px; max-width: 100px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body mt-3">
                            <h2 class="account-heading">User: {{user.username}}</h2>
                            <p class="text-secondary">Email: {{user.email}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {%csrf_token%}
                        <fieldset class='form-group'>
                            <legend class='border-bottom mb-4'>Update your details</legend>
                          {{user_form|crispy}}
                        </fieldset>
                        <div class='form-group'>
                            <button class='btn btn-outline-info' type="submit">Update</button>
                        </div>
                     </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to specify related_name in your UserProfile class's user field, it is this attribute by which you'll later be allowed to do reverse query just add

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_profile")
```

and now in your signals

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.user_profile.save()
```

also look at [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) for reference

Comment: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /admin/login/
User has no user_profile. :(

Comment: have you tried `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`? Also try to create new user, the error message clearly states that profile for given your does not exist.

Comment: Yes I have. When creating new user I receive now save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'. Also, I had this before and tried to add args/kwards to save methods but still had no luck :(